# AJAX works in IE but not in Firefox or Chrome

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm new to using AJAX and my code works in Internet Explorer but not in Firefox or Chrome.

I do not know what it is exactly what should change in the code ...

// I think that error should be here :-)

```
function cerrar(div)
{
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById(div).innerHTML = '';
}
function get_ajax(url,capa,metodo){ 
    var ajax=creaAjax();
    var capaContenedora = document.getElementById(capa);
    if (metodo.toUpperCase()=='GET'){
        ajax.open ('GET', url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (ajax.readyState==1){
                capaContenedora.innerHTML= "<center><img src=\"imagenes/down.gif\" /><br><font color='000000'><b>Cargando...</b></font></center>";
            } else if (ajax.readyState==4){ 
                if(ajax.status==200){               
                    document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML=ajax.responseText; 
                }else if(ajax.status==404){
                    capaContenedora.innerHTML = "<CENTER><H2><B>ERROR 404</B></H2>EL ARTISTA NO ESTA</CENTER>";
                } else {
                    capaContenedora.innerHTML = "Error: ".ajax.status;
                }
            } // ****
        }
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajax.send(null);
        return
    }
}

function creaAjax(){
  var objetoAjax=false;
      try{objetoAjax = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
          catch(e){try {objetoAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");} 
        catch (E){objetoAjax = false;}}
     if(!objetoAjax && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
  objetoAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();}  return objetoAjax;
}
```

//These functions are connected with a form

```
function resultado(contenido){
                var url='ajax/buscar.php?'+ contenido +'';// Vota Resultado
                var capa='resultado';
                var metodo='get';
                get_ajax(url,capa,metodo);
}
function paginas(contenido){
                var url='ajax/paginar.php?'+ contenido +'';// Vota Paginas
                var capa='paginas';
                var metodo='get';
                get_ajax(url,capa,metodo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Strongly* suggest that you use a lib like jQuery that encapsulates a lot of what you're doing above, masking cross-browser issues (current and future).  Even if you don't want to use jQuery site-wide, you could still use it just for its AJAX functionality.